# Receptacle replacement

Tags: receptacle

I an trying to replace a receptacle that has 4 push-in wires and 2 more wires attached to the side screws. New receptacles won’t accept the 12ga. wire in the push holes. What’s my options?

Comment: Are you saying there are 3 hots and 3 neutrals hooked up to this receptacle, or 6 hots and 6 neutrals?

Comment: How about a picture of the existing outlet and the new outlet.

Comment: Some info is missing here: description of the complete circuit if possible, breaker size, voltage, maximal needed power at the outlets.

Comment: 3 hots and 3 neutrals.

Answer (score 4):

**Pigtails and Wire Nuts**

Use short pieces of 12 AWG wire as pigtails. If you have any 12 AWG NM (aka Romex) lying around, you can take a black and white wire out of that. Connect all the hots together with a black pigtail using a wire nut and connect the other end of the pigtail to a screw on the new receptacle. Same for all the neutrals with a white pigtail. All grounds should be together as well, using a bare or green wire.

Comment: ...and use the correct size of wirenut for the number & gauge of wires (and wind it tight! And pull on every wire to make sure they are all firmly connected.)